# How can I create a parent from a child model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I have a `Conversation` model that `has_many :messages` and a `Message` model that `belongs_to :conversation`. Conversations are created when a user sends the first message. Is there a way I can create a new `Conversation` upon sending a `POST` request to `/messages` in my messages controller?

Comment: Your controller can do whatever you want it to do. What is the problem here?

Comment: I'm having trouble wrapping my head around creating a child first, then the parent.

Comment: Thats because its not the solution. You're most likely stuck up on a beginner hangup where you assume that there is always a 1:1 mapping between controllers and models which isn't actually the case. Here you would query and see if a conversation exists and if not create it first and then create a message off it. The first task you really have to solve here is setting up a association between your users and conversations.

Comment: This is also a domain thats been done to death and you should be able to find plenty of tutorials covering how to build a basic messaging app with rails.

Comment: Do I have to set anything else for my associations other than what I stated in the main post? Also, yes, I've googled a lot and I can't find a satisfactory answer, my apologies if I seem lazy. Most tutorials covering chats assume people want to build general channels -> messages, but I want to build a private conversation between two users and two users only.